# Java exception when running wsimport.bat under openjdk-11

Tags: java, wsimport, openjdk-11

I downloaded wsimport and wanted to run it. However, when I run wsimport.bat I get an error message stating that classes could not be found. I use OpenJDK 11 on Windows 10.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1016)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:802)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:623)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:3138)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3343)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:2152)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:150)
    at com.sun.tools.ws.WsImport.main(WsImport.java:56)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.api.ErrorListener
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 24 more
```

What can I do to run wsimport.bat without errors?

Comment: make sure the right libraries/classes are on your classpath

Comment: what is the right classpath?

Comment: depends on your machine

Comment: Refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html to understand more about classpaths and include the appropriate libraries on the classpath.

Comment: I have set the path to the openjdk libs and to the jaxws-ri libs and I still get the exception

Comment: wsimport is part of JAX-WS.  JAX-WS is no longer part of the JDK.  And JAX-WS requires JAXB, which also is no longer part of the JDK.  Both JAX-WS and JAXB *are* part of Java EE, so I recommend you [download GlassFish](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/index.html) and use its `wsimport` command.